# Increment varchar column with update statement

Tags: sql-server

I need to update a column of type varchar such that the EmpName is set to EmpName1, EmpName2, EmpName3...for all rows.

Here's what I have tried but it doesn't work:

```
begin
declare @i int
declare @empprefix varchar(20)
declare @i2 varchar(20)
set @i = 0
set @empprefix = 'EmpName'
set @i2 = cast(@i as varchar(20))
while @@ROWCOUNT > 0
update dbo.employee
set EmpName = @empprefix+@i2
set @i=@i+1
commit;
```

Comment: Not sure what more I can offer to the question.

Comment: Try adding steps to create a table with test data. Then expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a common table expression and the [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) window function to assign a row number that could be used as the increment.  I'm assuming the employee table has some kind of unique column that we could use to order by for the `ROW_NUMBER` window function.  I'm using `id` in this example.

```
--demo setup
Declare @Employee table (id int, EmpName varchar(100))
insert into @Employee(id,EmpName) values(1,''),(2,''),(3,'')

--solution
--common table expression to assign a row number to each employee row ordered by id
;WITH _EmployeeWithRowNumber
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY id
            ) AS rn
    FROM @Employee
    )
--update empname to include row number
UPDATE e
SET empname = 'EmpName' + convert(VARCHAR(10), rn)
FROM _EmployeeWithRowNumber e

--verify results
SELECT *
FROM @Employee
```

---

```
| id | EmpName  |
|----|----------|
| 1  | EmpName1 |
| 2  | EmpName2 |
| 3  | EmpName3 |
```

Comment: That get's me close enough.  I just have to modify the select statement to get unique rows but this does the trick!  Thanks!

Comment: @supergirldba - That's awesome - you're welcome! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your query seems to begin infinity loop, and no `commit` required without `begin tran`.

However, If you want update existing rows in `Employee` table, you probably want to try this:

```
update e set e.EmpName = (e.EmpName + Cast(ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY e.EmpName) as varchar(5)) ) 
from  dbo.employee as e
```

Comment: You are correct.  I was testing so I probably didn't include exactly what I was running.  Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

"+" is not the valid operator to concatenate strings (or varchar) - ...

check https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Yes it is in T-SQL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/string-concatenation-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017